# Pivoting columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have below result set(ignore the column names, modified to show in form of columns) which is generated using the query given

```
Source RfrshCycleId SorceType CycleNmber CycleNme sltme RfrshCycleDetalId PublishTime
-------------------------------------------------------------------------  
Mercury 1   Summary 1   Cycle1  3:00:00 NULL    NULL
Mercury 2   Summary 3   Cycle3  6:00:00 1   4/21/15 4:32 AM
Mercury 3   Summary 5   Cycle5  10:00:00    NULL    NULL
Mercury 4   Summary 2   Cycle2  15:00:00    NULL    NULL
Mercury 5   Detail  1   Cycle1  8:00:00 NULL    NULL
Mercury 6   Detail  2   Cycle2  23:00:00    NULL    NULL
Mercury 7   Complete    1   Cycle1  3:00:00 2   4/18/15 1:42 AM
Mercury 8   Complete    3   Cycle3  6:00:00 NULL    NULL
Mercury 9   Complete    2   Cycle2  15:00:00    NULL    NULL
Mercury 10  Complete    4   Cycle4  18:00:00    NULL    NULL
```

The query used to get above resultset is :

```
SELECT 
    RC.Source As Source, RC.RefreshCycleId As RefreshCycleId,
    RC.SourceType As SourceType, RC.CycleNumber As CycleNumber,
    RC.CycleName As CycleName, RC.slatime As slatime,
    RCD.RefreshCycleDetailId As RefreshCycleDetailId,
    RCD.PublishTime As PublishTime
FROM
    RefreshCycles RC
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    RefreshCycleDetails RCD ON RC.RefreshCycleId = RCD.RefreshCycleID
WHERE 
    RC.Source = 'Mercury'
```

I want to get the result set as following

[image: pivoting in excel]

I tried unpivoting and then pivoting the resultset, but being new to pivot/unpivot, could not get the correct result. Kindly help.

Comment: The expected layout isn't a table, it looks like a report or Excel PivotTable snapshot. You can't produce hierarchical column layouts from SQL. What layout do you really want to produce?

Comment: Can you add what you tried?

Comment: You could produce that output with a matrix in SSRS or PivotTables in Excel, a SQL-query won't get you that output unfortunately.

Comment: I was trying to use the query generated in dataset of ssrs report..how can produce the output in matrix? If the first row where Mercury is written can be ignored..then is it possible to produce the remaining output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with SQL Server, and for good reason. This is a classic example of the distinction between data storage and data presentation. Your initial reaction to keep your data in normalised form is correct. You should investigate creating a linked server to an excel document to create a matrix report, or of course there is SSRS, which is a bit more involved and requires more work to set up.

Comment: i actually want to create a SSRS report..i was trying to use the generated query for the output as dataset..and use it in table...how can i create a SSRS matrix for the output that i need?